# C++ NOT bitwise operator binary char conversion

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am studying C++ from Primer 5th edition. One of the questions is:

> What is the value of ~'q' << 6 on a machine with 32-bit ints and 8 bit chars, that uses Latin-1 character set in which 'q' has the bit pattern 01110001?

What i am confused with is will the compiler convert the 'q' to 32-bit int before ~ or before <

As far as I understand it should work like so:

```
'q' = 01110001

~'q' = 10001110

~'q' << 6 = 00000000000000000010001110000000
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operator `~` performs integral promotions on its operand (C++11, `[expr.unary.op]§10`). Which means it will convert the `char` to `int` before doing the complement. So it will go like this:

```
'q' == 01110001

~ 'q' == ~ 00000000000000000000000001110001

~ 'q' == 11111111111111111111111110001110
```

Then comes a problem. We see the value of `~ 'q'` is negative. Left-shifting a negative value has undefined behaviour (`[expr.shift]§2`). *(Thanks to [@colombien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42300052/1782465) for pointing out this last part)*

Comment: Thanks! I was quite confused there! Do all bitwise operators perform integral promotions?

Comment: @Deohboeh Yes. Actually, even more: most arithmetic operators in general perform "usual arithmetic conversions," which (for integral types) start with integral promotion.

Comment: It is undefined as linked by @colombien

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is here: [Bitwise operators and signed types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141871/bitwise-operators-and-signed-types)

> The expression `~'q' << 6` results in undefined behavior.